# how to use specific encoding on NSXMLParser?

Tags: iphone, encoding, nsxmlparser

how to use specific encoding on NSXMLParser ?

It default on utf-8 ,I want to use on tis-620
any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a correct encoding info inside the xml (first line, e.g. <`?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) everything should work out of the box.

Comment: I would seriously consider converting that file to UTF-8 using some other tool, were I you. Variations in character encoding is a scourge upon programmers everywhere. Do the right thing: Use UTF-8. Always.